# I'm it possible to change the width of my website pages through admin panel

Tags: magento1.9.3.7

I'm trying to change the width of my website pages from around 66% to 85% width of the whole page. Can I do this in the Admin panel easily or will I have to change the CSS code from the server?

Comment: You have to do css your self.magento does not have the feature like that

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a custom theme with this functionality built in (unlikely), you will need to customise your theme in the codebase.

Comment: Im using the ultimo theme for my website and it does not allow for me to do this as far as i can see. Is there any guidelines or set instructions i should follow for changing my theme in the codebase.

Comment: It entirely depends on your theme so it's hard for me to say, if you navigate to `skin > frontend` you will see your available themes. Go into your theme directory and look for a folder named CSS. Your CSS files should be in here. If you see a directory named SCSS or SASS you'll need to compile these files with  SASS - https://sass-lang.com/